# Change the tabbing style in CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

In a Html page and when the Tab key is pressed,the tabbed link gets highlighted,
is it possible to change the style of that highlight?

Comment: [`MDN :focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [`:focus`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/focus/) pseudo class.

```css
textarea:focus {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<textarea>
 Test content
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the style by using the :focus pseudo selector. I've created a CodePen to show you: https://codepen.io/JosephAllen/pen/aabppo

You may want to disable the browser's default :focus state too:

```
a:focus {
    color: green;
    outline: none; // Removes Chrome's default blue border
}
```